# Remove square brackets from array?

Tags: ruby, tiny-tds

I have an array that I'm trying to load into a SQL statement.  When I compile the SQL statement and include the array, it also puts the `[]` brackets into the string, and I need to remove them in order to insert it into my DB.

Here's my code:

```
i = 0

while i < rows.length
     sql = "INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(#{rows[i]})"
     puts sql
end
```

Current output:

```
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(["value 1", "value 2", "value 3"])
```

Desired output:

```
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES("value 1", "value 2", "value 3")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `inspect` and `join`:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(#{rows[i].map{|x| x.inspect}.join(', ')})"
```

- `map` calls a block on each element of an array, then sets that element to the return value of the block
- `inspect` turns a string into its representation (like `"the string"` (with quotation marks around it))
- `join` puts them all together with a delimiter in between

Comment: oh, you are my hero sir!  I kept trying to use join(', '), but it was giving me an error.  thank you!  can accept answer in 10 minutes.

Comment: Don't use `inspect`, that's a really error-prone way to accomplish a very simple problem. `inspect` can be overwritten to provide custom output when inspecting objects while debugging, which would affect the output you're looking for.

Comment: @theTinMan Then what would you suggest instead? Also, I don't know why you would override `inspect` for strings...

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you're seeing:

```
ary = ['value 1', 'value 2', 'value 3']
"#{ ary }" # => "[\"value 1\", \"value 2\", \"value 3\"]"
```

which is the "inspected" output, caused by using [Array.to_s](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-inspect) AKA [Array.inspect](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-inspect). Looking at it like we'd normally see it:

```
puts "#{ ary }"
# >> ["value 1", "value 2", "value 3"]
```

And here's how to fix it:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(#{ ary.map{ |i| '"%s"' % i }.join(', ') })" 
# => "INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(\"value 1\", \"value 2\", \"value 3\")"

puts sql
# >> INSERT INTO my_table VALUES("value 1", "value 2", "value 3")
```

`'"%s"' % i` is a [String `format`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-25) that wraps a string in double-quotes.

That all said, the proper way to communicate with a database these days is to use a decent ORM. Ruby has several of them, of which I favor [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/). The *major* win for an ORM is it removes the close dependency of your code to the language used by the database. Read through the [list of databases](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-adapters/index.html) it supports, without needing to change anything in your code beyond the DSN needed to connect.

> Sequel currently has adapters for ADO, Amalgalite, CUBRID, DataObjects, DB2, DBI, Firebird, IBM_DB, Informix, JDBC, MySQL, Mysql2, ODBC, OpenBase, Oracle, PostgreSQL, SQLAnywhere, SQLite3, Swift, and TinyTDS.

Notice, TinyTDS is listed.

Migrations work, queries work, inserts, deletes, updates, everything is abstracted, which is a huge win as you migrate to bigger/other systems. You can start with SQLite locally, use MySQL or PostgreSQL, then switch to Oracle without code changes, just tweak the DSN.

Read through the first page of the site, along with [the README](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/README_rdoc.html), and you'll get an idea of how easy it is to use, and wonder why you've done it any other way.

Comment: `INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(value 1, value 2, value 3)` is not valid SQL... you're missing the `"`s.

Comment: @the Tin Man - +1 for the added info on sequel.  I'll look into it.